# cakephp site domain change, having 301 issues

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, http-status-code-301

I moved my cakephp site from a subdomain over to a different domain. I handled the permanent redirect in my htaccess file but in the redirect i am losing my neat/clean url handling.

old site
iphone.gameachievements.org

new site
gameachievements.org

example of current redirect
iphone.gameachievements.org/games/jungle-swing  -> 
gameachievements.org/index.php?url=games/jungle-swing

what i want.. is
iphone.gameachievements.org/games/jungle-swing  -> 
gameachievements.org/games/jungle-swing

here is what my htaccess file looks like...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} iphone.gameachievements.org
    RewriteRule (.*) http://gameachievements.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

any help is appricated 
thanks

m!

Answer (score 1):

Put this first:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} iphone.gameachievements.org
RewriteRule (.*) http://gameachievements.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```